# how to resolve this sql query inside laravel controller

Tags: sql, laravel

I am getting **internal server error 500** when I pass this query inside my Laravel controller. Is there any alternative to write this?

```php
$var1 = $request->xyz;
$var2 = $request->abc;
$take = $request->take;
$skip = $request->skip;

$sample = DB::table('table_name')
  ->select('table_name.*', DB::raw('COUNT(column_name) as total_count'))
  ->where('column_name1', $var1)
  ->where('column_name2', $var2)
  ->offset($skip)
  ->limit($take)
  ->get();

$encrypted = AESEncrypt($sample);
return json_encode($encrypted);
```

Comment: What is the actual error description that PHP provides, beyond error 500? Also try looking in `/storage/logs` to see if any query was actually executed.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk the log states - `local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::count() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection::count() at vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager.php:349)`

Comment: Is this your entire accurate code because based on the error you are getting does not seem likely to be coming from this code.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `->select('column_name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_count'))`
and also try `\DB::`